# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$blog" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ElParador-login\blog_poo\modelo\manejo_objetos.php on line 39

Tags: php, mysql

AYUDA NO ENCUENTRO EL ERROR ESTOY APRENDIENDO PHP Y NO PUEDO ENCONTRAR EL ERROR EN LA VARIABLE YA BUSQUÉ EN LOS DEMÁS ARCHIVOS Y NADA
ESTOY CREANDO UN BLOG COMO SE DARÁN CUENTA

```
    include("objeto_blog.php"); 
    

    class manejo_objetos {

        private $conexion;

        public function __construct($conexion) {
            $this->setConexion($conexion);
        }

        public function setConexion(PDO $conexion) {
            $this->conexion=$conexion;
        } 

        public function getContenidoPorFecha() {
            $matriz=array();
            $contador=0;

            $resultado=$this->conexion->query("SELECT * FROM CONTENIDO ORDER BY FECHA");
            while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $blog=new objeto_blog();

                $blog->setId($registro["id"]);
                $blog->setTitulo($registro["titulo"]);
                $blog->setFecha($registro["fecha"]);
                $blog->setComentario($registro["comentario"]);
                $blog->setImagen($registro["imagen"]);

                $matriz[$contador]=$blog;

                $contador++;
            }
            return $matriz;
        }
        
        public function insertaContenido(objeto_blog $blog) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO CONTENIDO (titulo, fecha, comentario, imagen) VALUES ('" . $blog->getTitulo() . "','" . $blog->getFecha() . "','" . $blog->getComentario() . "','" $blog->getImagen() . "')";

            $this->conexion->query($sql);

        }
            

    }
        
        
        
        
        
?>
```

Comment: Explayate porfas

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora me dice esto: Fatal error: Cannot declare class objeto_blog, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\ElParador-login\blog_poo\modelo\objeto_blog.php on line 2

Comment: Funcionó igual lo que vos pusiste, y ahora dice otra cosa

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad y así evitas que tu pregunta sea cerrada.

Comment: Y cual es el contenido de `objeto_blog.php`?